# Displaying selected data from Google Calendar on web page?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I appreciate there have been several questions of this nature, but none seems to address my particular (simple!) need.

I have an Apps Script function that happily accesses a public Google calendar and extracts the events for today, and I can list these on the console quite happily.

What I now want to do is to put these events on an HTML web page.  The events can change often during the day, so people want to be able to see the latest data when they load my web page.  It seemed like a simple matter, but the more I look into it, the more confused I get!

Is there an easy way to do this, or am I going to have to get involved with Google APIs etc?

Thanks.

Perhaps I should add that I know I could just embed the calendar in the page, but all the user wants to know is "Is the facility open at the moment/later today" and not have to manipulate a Google calendar.

Comment: There is an easy way to do it if you comfortable creating a webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some tweaking to the embed view, like showing a single day only. Here's an example:
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/embed?showNav=0&showPrint=0&showCalendars=0&mode=DAY&src=en.usa%23holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com

That said, I can understand not wanting to use iframes. The good news is that if you're already using Apps Script, you're already using the Calendar API.

The only thing new you need to do is enable the API create your own API key. Follow the instructions to:

- [Enable the Calendar API](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841)
- [Create an API key](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862)

I've simplified the [quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js) to work without OAuth (which is the majority of the complexity). You don't need to care about authorization for a public calendar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Calendar API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Google Calendar API</p>
    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // API key from the Developer Console
      var API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS =
        ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

      var CALENDAR_ID = 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com';


      function start() {
        gapi.client.init({
          'apiKey': API_KEY,
          'discoveryDocs': DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        }).then(function() {
          listUpcomingEvents();
        });
      }

      function onLoad() {
        gapi.load('client', start);
      }

      /**
       * Displays a list of events from the public calendar.
       * You'll need to tweak the rest to show the data you like.
       */

      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      function listUpcomingEvents() {
        gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
          'calendarId': CALENDAR_ID,
          'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
          'showDeleted': false,
          'singleEvents': true,
          'orderBy': 'startTime'
        }).then(function(response) {
          var events = response.result.items;
          appendPre('Upcoming holidays:');
          if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
              var event = events[i];
              var when = event.start.dateTime;
              if (!when) {
                when = event.start.date;
              }
              appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')');
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
          }
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload=onLoad();>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

See also [Google Calendar API Reference Docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

Comment: That's brilliant!  Thank you for your very comprehensive - and comprehensible - answer!